# Surface integral of an paraboloid cut by a plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the surface integral of the portion of the paraboloid $x^2+y^2=2ay$ cut by the plane $y=a$. My attempt was to substitute the plane on the equation for the paraboloid, and that would give the following integral, using polar coordinates, $$A = \iint_T r\ dr\ d\theta,$$ where $T : \{\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} \leq a^2\},$ so that means that I'm calculating the area of that ellipse, which results $A = 2 \pi ,$ but the right answer is $A = 2 \pi a^2 \frac{(3\sqrt{3} - 1)}{3}.$ I know I'm missing a lot, but I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing is wrong with "right answer" or with the problem statement.
I solve in cartesian coordinates as follow.

$x^2+y^2-2ay=0 \rightarrow y=a \pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Substituting $y$ for get the $x$ limits. 
$x^2+a^2-2a^2=x^2-a^2=0 \rightarrow x=\pm \lvert a \rvert$

Assuming $a>0$,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{y=a \pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{y=a} dy \,dx \\
&=\int_{-a}^{a}a-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \,dx \\
&=\int_{-a}^{a}\pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \,dx \\
&=\pm \dfrac{\pi a^2}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$